# Pinescript V5: Strategy exit for stop loss doesn't work when in long and short position

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have written a strategy for my indicator. I'm using ATR for TP/SL for long and for short positions. My problems

- The strategy tester doesn't exit my short position for SL while a new long order is open.
- The strategy doesn't exit my long position for SL, while a new short order is open.

**Please see below picture**, as you can see, the 'enter short' position with ID 578206 is not closed when price hit the SL for this short position.
[image]

This is the last piece of my code for TP/SL and entry and exit points:

```
alen = input(14, 'ATR Length (default 14)', group = 'Take Profit & Stoploss')
smooth = input(3, 'Smoothing', group = 'Take Profit & Stoploss')
TP_ATR_input = input(4.5, 'TP Multiplier', group = 'Take Profit & Stoploss')
SL_ATR_input = input(1.5, 'SL Multiplier', group = 'Take Profit & Stoploss')

datr = ta.atr(alen)
sclose = ta.sma(close, smooth)

SL_ATR_L = sclose - datr * SL_ATR_input
TP_ATR_L = sclose + datr * TP_ATR_input
SL_ATR_S = sclose + datr * SL_ATR_input
TP_ATR_S = sclose - datr * TP_ATR_input

// TP and SL Plots
plot(TP_ATR_L, 'TPLong', color=color.new(#1d8121, 0))
plot(SL_ATR_L, 'SLLong', color=color.new(color.maroon, 0))
plot(TP_ATR_S, 'TPShort', color=color.new(#1d8121, 0))
plot(SL_ATR_S, 'SLShort', color=color.new(color.maroon, 0))


longCondition = L_above_3ema and s3 ? high + 2 * atr : na
shortCondition = S_below_3ema and l3 ? low - 2 * atr : na

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("enter long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Exit long", from_entry = "enter long", limit = TP_ATR_L, stop = SL_ATR_L) 

if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("enter short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Exit short", from_entry = "enter short", limit = TP_ATR_S, stop = SL_ATR_S)
```

I have searched and used the following below code, still, its not working.

```
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit("TP short", from_entry = "enter short", limit = TP_ATR_S)
    strategy.exit("SL short", from_entry = "enter short", stop = SL_ATR_S)
```

Also I manage to automatically cancel the long order when new short order is openend and vice
versa, but that's not what I want to achieve.

**I want that every order (long/short) has it's own fixed TP and SL from entry point.** Or is this something that is not supported yet for pinescript?

Comment: @nawid-dailiry You should post you entire code as the strategy definition at the beginning of your code define how pinescript should behave when several order must occurs at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your short position is closed by entering a long position (because you cannot have a short and long position open at the same time) before the stop loss on the short position is reached.

This happens because the `longCondition` condition is reached when you are in a short position and may become true before the exit occurs. You can add a check to the condition

```
longCondition = L_above_3ema and s3 and strategy.position_size >= 0 ? high + 2 * atr : na
```

so your condition will only work outside of a short position and the strategy will not be able to go long when a short position is already open.

Similarly, you need to fix ShortCondition by setting the reverse condition.

P.S.: what you call an ID is actually the number of contracts

> Please see below picture, as you can see, the 'enter short' position with ID 578206 is not closed when price hit the SL for this short position.